# Replace object ID with its repective Name in a WPF DataGrid (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Consider the following model...

> > > **DataModel**

[image: DataModel]

I've a WCF data Service (PMService) that exposes the datamodels to my JobsViewModel

> > > WCF Data Service

```
namespace PM.DataService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class PMService
    {

[OperationContract]
    public ObservableCollection<Job> GetAllJobs()
    {
        using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Jobs.ToList();
            result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
            return new ObservableCollection<Job>(result);
        }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public ObservableCollection<Status> GetStatuses()
    {
        using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Statuses.ToList();
            result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
            return new ObservableCollection<Status>(result);
        }
    }        
    }
}
```

> > > **JobsViewModel**

```
namespace PM.UI.ViewModel
{
    public class JobsViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private PMServiceClient serviceClient = new PMServiceClient();

    public JobsViewModel()
    {
        this.RefreshAllJobs();
    }

    private void RefreshAllJobs()
    {
        this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.AllJobs = e.Result;
        };
        this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsAsync();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs;
    public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
    {
        get{
            return this.allJobs;
        }
        set
        {
            this.allJobs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllJobs");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Status> statuses;
    public ObservableCollection<Status> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statuses;
        }

        set
        {
            this.statuses = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Statuses");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

I included my viewmodel in the MainWindow.xaml

> > > **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PM.FullClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PM.UI"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:PM.UI.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="475" Width="575">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:JobsViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Using a DataGrid i've successfully displayed all the jobs.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllJobs}" Margin="6">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=jobNo}" Header="Job #" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=jobStatus}" Header="Status" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=jobDate}" Header="Date" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Statuses}" Header="Status" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

> > > **JobsDataGrid_output**

[image]

In the JobsDataGrid as you can see i've **IDs** of the Statuses.

Now the Statuses and Jobs have a one to many relationship where; a Job will hold the primary key of a Status.

What i want to do is **show the respective statusCaption insted of an the jobStatus**(statusId).

**Edited as Ucodia adviced**

I Inserted the code below

```
...
var result = context.Jobs.ToList();
    result.ForEach(e => context.LoadProperty(e, "Status"));
    result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
...
```

and the result is still the same (the Status coloumn is still blank

I run the app in debug mode and got the following... hoping it'll help someone explain me what I'm doing wrong.

**>>>Screenshot of debug data**
[image: Debug info]

Comment: Finally i disabled the Lazyloading and it works fine. But i know lazyloading is a feature that shouldn't be ignored so i would like to know what i have done wrong. For now, since @Ucodia lead me to a temporary solution I'll mark it as the answer. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `Job` objects to your DataGrid and in the columns you bind the `jobStatus` member which is the status ID that your object model uses to navigate to the concrete `Status` object to which the `statusCaption` member belong.

So you just need to change your second column binding to use the `Status` navigation property of the `Job` object.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=Status.statusCaption}" Header="Status" />
```

---

Later I realised that you were detaching your job objects from their context on load. By default, navigation properties like Status on the Job model will be lazy loaded, which means they will be loaded only when requested. But for the model to be lazy loaded, it needs to be attached. Therefore, when loading your Job objects you also need to explicitely ask for the Status property to be loaded before detaching the entity.

```
using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
{
    var result = context.Jobs.ToList();
    result.ForEach(e => context.LoadProperty(e, "Status"));
    result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
    return new ObservableCollection<Job>(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanx Ucodia, I actually tried that before, tried it again... i don't think it's that simple. If you think about it, the DataGrid is already bound to "AllJobs" so there is more to be done before i can simple set "Path=Status.statusCaption"... Any more ideas???

Comment: Actually it should work because if the DataGrid is bound to a list of Job (AllJobs), then the column will automatically be bound to Job objects. Can you try to run the application and watch for DataBinding errors in Visual Studio output window?

Comment: I've checked the output window and found nothing special... What i meant was a Job doesn't contain Status objects. It's the other way around. If you look at my datamodel once again, you'll realize that Status is the parent class cox it contains the primary key. So each Status will have multiple Jobs, and each Job simple has a reference to the Status object (jobStatus). I'm starting to think that my datamodel isn't following the best practices. I hope I'm wrong and there must be a better way. Please help...

Comment: could you elaborate little more on this issue? Thanx

Comment: Ok I think I understood what was going wrong. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanx Ucodia @Ucodia, that line of code didn't do the trick. I've edited the question and included some debug info. It might help what you were trying to explain.

Comment: Your update just revealed an issue that is different than the one in your original post. Indeed your context is not able to load navigation properties. You should open another question and ask why your context does not load navigation properties such as Status.

Comment: you are right. I've some issue at the entity data model level. When i checked the result before detaching the context, I have the statuses for the jobs. But after detaching it's lost. When i removed the detached line, i get an "....The connection was closed unexpectedly" error.